# How can I route a url with an asp extension if the file does NOT exist, but route to the file if it does?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've got a legacy site that's a hybrid of Classic ASP and WebForms/ASPX.  I want to migrate the whole thing to MVC, and my first goal is to be able to route requests for ASP files to new controllers and views, as I migrate ASP to MVC.  I want to make it so that a request for an ASP file that exists is handled by the file itself (legacy mode), but I want to be able to delete an ASP file and migrate its functionality to a controller and view, and have MVC detect that the file is not present, and route to the controller.

I tried this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            "ASP",
            "{resource}.asp/{*pathInfo}",
            New With {.controller = "Asp", .action = "Index"}
        )
```

But it simply doesn't work.  If I request the page `/xyz.asp`, which does not exist, I simply get a 404, and the route is ignored.

How can I enabled the behavior that I want?

Comment: You need to make IIS route the file to ASP.Net too. What IIS version?

Comment: I'm on Windows 8, so I guess it's IIS 8.  But whatever I do has to work on the production web server, which I believe is running IIS 7.

Comment: @SLaks: I turned on `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` and this actually has the desired behavior, but, of course, it's a bit heavyweight in that it, well, runs all managed modules for all requests, including js, css, jpg, etc.  Is there any other way to get what I need without that overhead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269370/httphandler-fire-only-if-file-doesnt-exist) and [this post on HttpHandlers by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx), I decided to do it this way:

I moved all .asp files to a different location called, say, LegacyAsp

I added an HttpHandler called, say, LegacyAspHandler, and configure it in web.config to handle any request for an ASP file:

```
  <add name="LegacyAspHandler" verb="*" path="*.asp"
    type="MyNamespace.LegacyAspHandler, MyAssembly" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
```

In the handler, I transform the incoming request path, which is looking for a file on disk, to look for that same file in the new location:

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    'the path to the legacy version
    Dim sPath = context.Request.PhysicalPath.Replace([OriginalPath], "LegacyAsp")

    'if the physical file exists
    If System.IO.File.Exists(sPath) Then
        'transfer to it
        context.Server.TransferRequest(context.Request.RawUrl.Replace([OriginalPath], "LegacyAsp"))
        Return
    End If

    'do the logic that replaces the missing ASP page

    'write the result so that the client sees it
    context.Response.Write([New Content])
End Sub
```

This way, if the original ASP file is present, it is used, and if it is not present, we use the new ASP.NET logic.  So I can leave the Classic ASP stuff in place, but as I port the logic to .NET, it seamlessly switches over.